# SQL window function ordering issue

Tags: sql-server

I have a dataset that can have a location with multiple specialties.  I'm trying to just choose one specialty based on the following criteria:

1. If Primary = 'Y' then choose Primary over Boardcertified
2. If Primary = 'N' and Boardcertified = 'Y', then choose Boardcertified
3. If both = 'N' then chose either record

   ```
   declare @t table(id int, location varchar(250), specialty varchar(250), boardcertified char, primaryspeciality char)

   insert into @t values(1, 'Dallas', 'Maternal', 'Y', 'N'),
                        (1, 'Dallas', 'Obstetrics', 'Y', 'Y'),
                        (2, 'Plano', 'Maternal', 'Y', 'N'),
                        (2, 'Plano', 'Peds', 'N', 'N'),
                        (3, 'Arlington', 'Peds', 'N', 'N'),
                        (3, 'Arlington', 'Maternal', 'Y', 'Y')
   ```

I'm been trying to solve this with a window function, like this:

```
    select * from
    (
    select *, row_number()over(partition by id, location
                               order by case when primaryspeciality = 'Y' then 1
                                         when boardcertified = 'Y' then 2
                                         end desc) as rn
from @t)a
    where rn = 1
```

This gives me the following result:

```
    id    location   specialty    boardcertified   primaryspecialty 
    1       Dallas     Maternal     Y                 N
```

What I actually want is:

```
    id     location   specialty    boardcertified   primaryspecialty
    1       Dallas    Obstetrics      Y               Y
```

Since primaryspecialty = 'Y' for Dallas and Obstretics I would want that record.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: just remove the `desc` in the `order by`

Comment: That's pretty embarrassing.  Thank you!

Comment: no problem, we've all been there some time

Answer (score 1):

I *think* this is what you're after:

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id, [location]
                              ORDER BY CASE primaryspeciality WHEN 'Y' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
                                       CASE boardcertified WHEN 'Y' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
                                       id) AS RN
    --If you want the id to be random each time when they are both 'Y' (as you said it could be any), replace id with NEWID()
    FROM @t)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1;
```

Note the uses of multiple `CASE` expressions.

Comment: I believe this is more of what I'm looking for.  I just ran into an issue where one record had an 'N' for BoardCertified and PrimarySpeciality, but the other record had a 'Y' for both.  This way picked the correct record.